# MySQL Maximum Row Size is L characters plus 3=65535

Tags: mysql, size, row, max

MySQL documentation defines the maximum row size in a table as 65535 or 2**16-1.
The maximum column size is L characters + two bytes to specify the size.

Executing the following commands complained of row size failed:

```
create table_row_size (
 a varchar(65533)
);
```

The following one passes:

```
create table_row_size (
 a varchar(65532)
);
```

So where is that extra byte being used?

I am using 5.5.19 with an Innodb Engine

Comment: nullable? will varchar(65533) NOT NULL work?

Comment: Please stop signing your posts, and it's time to accept some answers to your previous questions -- you've indicated that some solved your problems.

Comment: Also, 1 year 8 months is more than enough time to read the formatting FAQ and begin formatting your posts.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mark the column as NOT NULL in order to get 65533 as the maximum VARCHAR length.

Comment: And by the way, the max size will vary based on the CHARSET you use for the table.

Comment: Nice! I tried it and you definitely know your material! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't defined `a` as being `NOT NULL`, an extra byte is needed to keep track of that. MySQL uses one bit of flags (rounded up to the nearest byte) for each nullable column.

Note that, for large data, it's generally preferable to use a `TEXT` or `BLOB` column, as those are stored separately from the row.